# Pressing CTRL+C in Google Code issue tracker makes the browser navigate away

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, google-code

Whenever I want to copy/paste something in Google Code's issues tool ([example](https://code.google.com/p/ankidroid/issues/detail?id=77)), I press CTRL+C, and it triggers the shortcut "compose a new issue", navigating to a new page.

It is very bothersome, as I manage a lot of issues, and I often press CTRL+C.
Is there a way to disable this shortcut?

Comment: which web browser do you use ? can't reproduce it on Chrome

Comment: Sorry: Using Firefox 3.6.13 on Ubuntu 2010.10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switching to Firefox 4 apparently solved the problem.